# Почему при вводе в командную строку npm start выходит ошибка?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\vladimir.tedeev\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vladimir.tedeev\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vladimir.tedeev\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-06T16_00_25_123Z-debug.log
```

Comment: В консоле введи: "cd путь к папке с твоим проектом", а потом снова попробуй.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка пишет,что нет файла package.json в той папке, в которой вы вызываете, либо перейдите в папку с проектом, где он уже есть, либо создайте package.json с помощью `npm init`.